# UPSERT unless the date is the same

Tags: postgresql, insert, unique-constraint, python, upsert

There's a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table00 (
  userid     int8    PRIMARY KEY,
  save       date    NOT NULL,
  value      int4
);
```

where I want to upsert values IFF the `date` is not the same for a given `userid`, which I'm doing like so:

```
INSERT  INTO table00 (userid,save,value)  VALUES (%s,%s,%s)
ON CONFLICT (userid)  DO UPDATE  SET save=EXCLUDED.save, value=EXCLUDED.value
WHERE table00.save!=EXCLUDED.save;
```

But I'd prefer to add

```
CREATE  UNIQUE INDEX  ON table00   (userid, save);
```

and **drop the `WHERE` clause**. Is that possible?

But this isn't working, since values are still being updated even if they're on the same day; ie. the `ON CONFLICT` seems to swallow up all errors and do the upsert anyways regardless of any uniqueness constraints.

The logic I want is: "If the `userid` doesn't exist, then insert a new row. If the `userid` exists, then update its row, **unless** the date is the same, in which case **fail**."

So, something like:

```
INSERT  INTO table00 (userid,save,followers)  VALUES (%s,%s,%s)
ON CONFLICT (userid)  DO UPDATE SET  save=EXCLUDED.save, followers=EXCLUDED.followers
ON CONFLICT (userid,date)  ERROR;
```

Comment: have you tried to use a triggers

Comment: Since `userid` is the PK, your desired unique index on `(userid, save)` does nothing useful (unless you want to point a multicolumn FK constraint to it). Also, updating a row never conflicts with itself, a unique index is the wrong tool. The `WHERE` clause you have is the right tool. Why would you want to break it?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The unique index on `(userid, save)` is because I want to disable updates that happen on the same `date` (ie. any given row must be updated at most once per day). Let me know if it still doesn't make sense to have the unique index, because your observation is spot on. The only reason I want to do this is because I'm handling this situation in different table (with slightly different logic) with a unique index on `(userid, save)`, and I'd like to handle the 2 tables in the same manner, for consistency.

Comment: Also, the `WHERE` solution doesn't throw an error on conflicts (which is not the fault of `WHERE`, but of `ON CONFLICT`, I think), and the result is that I need different logic to handle each of the 2 tables, making my code uglier... (I'm using Postgres from Python with `psycopg2`)

Comment: If you don't want to update in case of duplicate rows, then use `on conflict do nothing`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thing is, I want to `update` when there's ONLY a conflict of userid, and `do nothing` when there's a conflict of BOTH `userid` and `date` (ie. a userid is getting a data update twice in a single day)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` with the `WHERE` condition as you showed it.

Then check how many rows were affected, and if there was none, throw an error. You can do that either in client code or in a database function.

With psycopg2, you can get the number of rows modified from the [`rowcount`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount) property of the cursor, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24441715/6464308).

Comment: Cheking how many rows were affected... How can I do that? Is that `O(n)`?

Comment: That's part of the result state of the `INSERT`. What API are you using to access PostgreSQL?

Comment: asyncpg and psycopg2

Comment: Ah, wait, this also doesn't really suit me very well because I'm trying to minimize write operations to disk. So, ideally we'd check **first** whether our intended write is going to modify a row or not. Obviously this can be done by executing another query first that specifically checks for this, but I wonder if the whole thing can be done in a single query (which is definitely more elegant, and maybe even faster)

Comment: Simply get the `rowcount` from the cursor, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24441715/6464308).

Answer (score 0):

So Laurenz had no way of knowing, but, in looking for the most elegant way of  doing this, the solution was to modify the `INSERT` in the OTHER table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table01(
  userid     int8 NOT NULL,
  save       date NOT NULL,
  followers  int4
);
CREATE  UNIQUE INDEX  ON table01 (userid,save);
```

```
INSERT  INTO table01 (userid,save,followers)  VALUES (%s,%s,%s)  ON CONFLICT (userid,save)  DO NOTHING
```

Now each of the 2 tables can be updated in a single Postgres query and without  extra Python boilerplate or logic checks.

Another major advantage (on top of elegance & consistency) is that now I can do all the Postgres operations in a single transactions (because now no transaction raises an Exception), which has speed up writes by ~5x.

So the Python code now looks like:

```
  async with pool.acquire() as conn, conn.transaction():
    for account in accounts:
      # get data

      # 1) put profile
      await conn.execute('''INSERT  INTO tt_profiles (userid,save,load,username,country,verified,following,followers,likes,videos,engagement,created,nickname,signature)  VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14)
        ON CONFLICT (userid)  DO  UPDATE SET save=EXCLUDED.save,username=EXCLUDED.username,verified=EXCLUDED.verified,following=EXCLUDED.following,followers=EXCLUDED.followers,likes=EXCLUDED.likes,videos=EXCLUDED.videos,engagement=EXCLUDED.engagement,created=EXCLUDED.created,nickname=EXCLUDED.nickname,signature=EXCLUDED.signature
        WHERE tt_profiles.save!=EXCLUDED.save''', userid,save,load,username,country,verified,following,followers,likes,videos,engagement,created,nickname,signature)

      # 2) put series
      await conn.execute('INSERT  INTO tt_series (userid,save,following,followers,likes,videos,engagement)  VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)  ON CONFLICT (userid,save)  DO NOTHING', userid,save,following,followers,likes,videos,engagement)
```

which is really clean and much faster.